# How to Inject script only in a particular Iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, javascript-injection, requestly

I am using Requestly to Inject script but couldn't find a way to inject the script only in a particular Iframe.

Is there any way to insert custom JS using Requestly in a particular iFrame in a webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requestly doesn't provide additional filters in Script Injection to detect whether you are injecting in Parent Page or Iframe.

However, there's one trick you can do.

You can additional checks in your script so that It only executes inside Iframe something like this

```
if (window.self !== window.top) {
    // Your script code goes here
}
```

However, If you can define your URL Pattern such that It only matches the Iframe then it's even better. Then you don't have to add this check but do better URL targeting such that Script Injection only works with Iframe URL and not parent URL.